# Segmentation Fault for an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have to find the index of the largest element in an array using a function and I keep getting a Segmentation fault error. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int numberOfElements, index;
int main()
{
  #define array_size 100
  int array[array_size]; 
  printf("The number of elements is:\n");
  scanf("%d", numberOfElements);
  for( index=0; index< numberOfElements ; index++)
  { 
    printf("The elements are: \n");
    scanf("%d", &array[index]);
  }

  int largestElementOfTheArray = largest(array, numberOfElements);
  printf("The largest element of the array is on position:%d\n",
                   largestElementOfTheArray );
  return 0;
}

int largest(int a[100], int n)
{
  int max=0;
  int indexOfLargest;
  int index;
  for(index = 0; index< n; index++)
  {
    if(a[index] >= max)
    {
      max = a[index];
      indexOfLargest = index;
    }

  }

  return indexOfLargest;
}
```

This is my code. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The reason it worked is that your original code declared `numberOfElements` with [static storage duration](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4) without an explicit [initializer](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10), so it was *0*. You passed the value *0* as is ([UB](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p1)), though the [conversion specifier `%d`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12) expects a pointer to signed integer. Now it possibly interpreted the integer value *0* as the pointer and tried to dereference and write through it.

Comment: Replace scanf("%d", numberOfElements) with scanf("%d", &numberOfElements)